# C# Grouping with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, grouping

I have an enumerable `t` of items that expose a property `X` which is an integer.
I would like to count the number of elements with `X < 0`, `X == 0` and `X > 0`.
Sure I can fire three statements like this:

```csharp
var p = t.Count(a => a.X < 0);
var q = t.Count(b => b.X == 0);
var r = t.Count(c => c.X > 0);
```

But this trigger [CA1851](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1851) (Possible multiple enumerations of `IEnumerable` collection).
What is a better way to get the three numbers via a single enumeration using Linq ?

Comment: It is easy to do with for loop, why do you want to complicate?

Comment: Looping through around 5 million records sounds not so good to me ;-)

Comment: withaggregate you can do something like `source.Aggregate(
    (CountA: 0, CountB: 0),
    (a, x) => {
        var ca = (x < 0 ) ? a.CountA+1:a.CountA;
        var cb = (x > 0) ? a.CountB+1:a.CountB;
        return (ca, cb);
    }   ));` coded on phone

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar why bother rewriting a function with a loop when the function already exist

Comment: @displayname _Looping through ~5 million records_, does that mean that you actually work on a DB ? Is `t` an `IEnumerable` or a `IQueryable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this is with `GroupBy`:

```cs
var x = input
       .GroupBy(k=> (
          k  < 0 ? 1 : 0,
          k == 0 ? 1 : 0,
          k  > 0 ? 1 : 0)
        )
       .OrderByDescending(g=>g.Key)
       .Select(k=>k.Count())
       .ToArray();

(int ltz, int zzz, int gtz) val = (x[0], x[1], x[2]);
```

Commenters astutely pointed out that this approach is missing certain details from the OP and defensive code. Also, agree that `Math.Sign` does this nicely, was loath to repeat. Here goes:

```cs
var x = t.
    .Select(i=>i.X)
    .Concat(new[] { -1, 0, 1})
    .GroupBy(Math.Sign)
    .OrderBy(k=>k.Key)
    .Select(k=>k.Count())
    .ToArray();

   if(x != null && x.Any())
       (int ltz, int zzz, int gtz) val = (x[0]-1, x[1]-1, x[2]-1);
```

Comment: Isn't `GroupBy(x => Math.Sign(x.X))` more clear ?

Comment: Yes, that´s why I first seelcted it as solution for my question. But finally used the originally posted answer no ".GroupBy(...)" and sorry, that was the reason why I changed my mind and selected this answer as the solution. Sorry for that :-( Dont kow whether this is ok for the community...

Comment: OP said the item has a `X`-property, where is it? This doesn't work at all. What if there are no items in input? Exception. What if there are no items which `X` is lower than 0? Exception or wrong result. What if there are no items which `X` is equal 0? Exception or wrong result. What if there are no items which `X` is higher than 0? Exception. The problem is that the `GroupBy` might not build 3 groups and then you don't know which index refers to which information.

Comment: All fair points @TimSchmelter, I suppose this illustrates the conceptual solution to the posed question, boiled down to the key logic. Perhaps naïvely, I am assuming that the OP can figure out how to apply this to an object with property X, and how to account for missing categories.

Comment: @TimSchmelter for me as OP it´s not really important that I can copy and paste code. So it´s not really needed that it works as posted by someone. I need more the idea behind it. And the first code snippet provides it.s So for me it´s fine :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-7.0) which is similar than a `GroupBy` or `ToDictionary`, but has the advantage that you can even ask for items which don't exist, you get an empty enumerable then:

```
var xLookup = t.ToLookup(x => Math.Sign(x.X)); // Sign returns -1, 0 or 1
int negativeCount = xLookup[-1].Count();
int zeroCount = xLookup[0].Count();
int positiveCount = xLookup[1].Count();
```

Oraces idea with [`Math.Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=net-7.0) is also good to keep the code short and clear.

The lookup is efficient like a dictionary but it comes with a memory cost. You can use following approach that needs almost no (permanent) memory and just takes a bit more time for execution:

```
var countDict = users.GroupBy(x => Math.Sign(x.X)).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
int countNegative = countDict.TryGetValue(-1, out int cNeg) ? cNeg : 0;
int countZero = countDict.TryGetValue(0, out int cZero) ? cZero : 0;
int countPositive = countDict.TryGetValue(1, out int cPos) ? cPos : 0;
```

Here i am loading a `Dictionary<int, int>`, the key is -1, 0 or 1(the sign) and the value is the count. So it's calculated directly not if you ask for it.

Comment: You may want to use `Math.Sign`: `var xLookup = b.ToLookup(Math.Sign);`

Comment: @Orace: good idea, adopted :)

Comment: WOW, thanks and learned again something! Reply marked as answer! Thanks!

Comment: Numbers higher than zero are called positive numbers, and numbers lower than zero are negative numbers. So what about renaming `lowerThanZeroCount` into `negativeCount` and `higherThanZeroCount` into `positiveCount`?

Comment: @displayname: i have edited my answer to provide another way which needs less memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I may be wrong but it seems to me that your latest version is still `O(n)` (because of `GroupBy`, and I suppose it's _LINQ to Objects_).

Comment: @Orace: both versions are set based approaches so not really O(n). The 1st processes all items/data to build 3 groups and add them to a dictionary like collection. The 2nd builds the groups in the database if available(OP didn't say that he uses a DB), then a dictionary with 0-3 entries is created which contains 0-3 int-values for the counts. So it needs much less (permanent) memory, but it's lil bit slower than the Loopkup(tested with 10mio. items).

Answer (score 3):

[Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240)  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74547073/361177) flaw is an `O(n)` memory usage.

[EnumerationQuest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnumerationQuest) NuGet package¹ purpose is to solve this kind of tasks, single enumeration is guaranteed and the memory usage is constant:

```csharp
var (p,q,r) = t.GetCount(v => v < 0)
               .AndCount(v => v == 0)
               .AndCount(v => v > 0);
```

[MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) NuGet package has many `Aggregate` overloads that allow multiple `Aggregate` in one enumeration, but you have to hand write the accumulators:

```csharp
var (p, q, r) = t.Aggregate(0, (pAcc, v) => pAcc + (v < 0 ? 1 : 0),
                            0, (qAcc, v) => qAcc + (v == 0 ? 1 : 0),
                            0, (rAcc, v) => rAcc + (v > 0 ? 1 : 0),
                            (pAcc, qAcc, rAcc) => (pAcc, qAcc, rAcc));
```

The optimal solution is probably a simple `foreach` loop:

```csharp
var p = 0;
var q = 0;
var r = 0;
foreach (var value in t)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case < 0:
            p++;
            break;
        case 0:
            q++;
            break;
        case > 0:
            r++;
            break;
    }
}
```

¹ I developed this package.

Answer (score 1):

You might write an extension method, which allows several counts and performs them in one loop (over the input enumerable):

```
public static int[] MultiCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, params Func<T,bool> functions[])
{
   int[] result = new int[functions.Length];
   foreach(var entry in input)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < functions.Length; i++)
      {
         if(functions[i].Invoke(entry))
         {
             result[i]++;
         }
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Usage would be

```
int[] counts = t.MultiCount(
    a => a.X < 0,
    b => b.X == 0,
    c => c.X > 0);

int p = counts[0];
int q = counts[1];
int r = counts[2];
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RZBUMD

Answer (score 0):

With aggregations, you can have multiple count or other aggregation method running :

```
var baseInput = new []{1,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,-1,0};
var inputs = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x=> baseInput[x%baseInput.Count()]);
var result = inputs.Aggregate(
    (CountPositive: 0, CountNegative: 0, CountZero: 0, SumPossitive:0),
    (a, x) =>
    {
        var pos = (x>0) ? a.CountPositive + 1 : a.CountPositive;
        var neg = (x<0) ? a.CountNegative + 1 : a.CountNegative;
        var zer = (x==0) ? a.CountZero + 1 : a.CountZero;
        var sumPos = a.SumPossitive+x;
        return (pos, neg, zer, sumPos);
    });

Console.WriteLine(result);

> (34, 33, 33, 1)
```

Demo:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YZJVq4 .

Comment: This doesn't provide the specific value expected in the question and is less readable than a good old `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Orace, there is no specific input nor output . So I changed the test to something more explicite. without having to hand populate an array of positive and negative value. 
for readability, yes It not a for/foreach loop.

Comment: OP want's to count negatives, null and positives values. The solution you provide gives the count of odd, even and multiple of 3 values. That's pretty unrelated for me.

Comment: For readability there should be nice way to get it via morLinQ partition or Aggregate. It's count by predicat. Same thing but sure.. Done. Is the fact that I show other aggregation method "sum" of topics there too?

Comment: See my updated answer for a MoreLinq implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to let you all know how I solved it.
Finally I implemented it this way:

```
public enum GroupEnum
{
    EqualToZero,
    LessThanZero,
    GreaterThanZero
}

var groups = (await t
                .GroupBy(item => item.X < 0
                                    ? GroupEnum.LessThanZero
                                    : (item.X == 0
                                           ? GroupEnum.EqualToZero
                                           : GroupEnum.GreaterThanZero
                        )
                ).Select(group => new { group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
                .ToListAsync())
                .Select(o => (Case: o.Key, Count: o.Count))
                .ToArray();
                
var equalToZero = groups.ToArray().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Case == GroupEnum.EqualToZero).Count;
var greaterThanZero = groups.ToArray().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Case == GroupEnum.GreaterThanZero).Count;
var lessThanZero = groups.ToArray().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Case == GroupEnum.LessThanZero).Count;
```

Comment: Why you create so many collections? `ToListAsync`, `ToArray`, `groups.ToArray()`, `groups.ToArray()`, `groups.ToArray()`.

Comment: ups ... you are right ... overseen that ... the last three var statements does not need the ".ToArray()" part. You have sharp eyes! Thanks!